# Training dataset generator in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, dataset

I'm working on my bachaleor theses called "Traffic sign detection in image and video" and I'm using neural network called YOLO (You Only Look Once). I think its name is pretty self-explaining, but paper may be found [here](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/yolo.pdf).
This network is learning from not-cropped annotated images (Regular networks use to train on cropped images). To be able to learn this network, i need not-cropped annotated european traffic signs dataset. I wasn't able to find any, even not [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/traffic-signs-dataset), so i decided to generate my own dataset.

---

First, I load many images of road taken from static camera on the car.
[image: See here.]

I've got few TRANSPARENT traffic (stop) signs like this

[image: See here.]

Then I'm doing few operations to make the traffic sign look "real" and copy it to random positions (where traffic signs usually are located). The size of traffic sign is adjusted due to its position in image -- closer to the middle sign is, the smaller sign is.

Operations I'm performing on traffic sign are:

- Blur sign with kernel of random size from 1x1 to 31x31.
- Rotate image left/right in X axis, random angle 0 to 20.
- Rotate image left/right in Z axis, random angle 0 to 30.
- Increase luminescence by adding/subtracting random value from 0 to 50

---

Here you may see few result examples (the better ones i guess): [click.](https://github.com/kocica/training-dataset-generator/tree/master/results)

Here is the source code: [click.](https://github.com/kocica/training-dataset-generator)

---

**Question:**

- Is there anything i could do to make the signs look more real and let the neural network train better ?

If the question would suit better for different kind of site, please, let me know.

Comment: assume a ground plane and compute homogeaphy correspondence. Then place your sign as if it was a 3D object by another homography transformstion (rotate around different axes. But to makd it look more real according to lighting conditions you'll probably need harder stuff like GANs. Not sure whether there are good solutions yet. Maybe have a look at blending techniques and panorama stitching about how they normalize lighting.

Comment: Hi @Micka, sorry for late reply. I've tried to train network with generated data few times and results are fine, you can see [here](https://github.com/kocica/training-dataset-generator/blob/master/results/comparison.pdf). First image is always output of network trained on real dataset, second is output of network trained on generated dataset. The obly problem now is that network trained on generated data has problem detecting small signs, while first network has not. I've tried to increase number of small signs in generated dataset but it did not help. Don't you have an idea what would help ?

Comment: github tells me "This file is too big to show. Sorry!"

Comment: did you use the initial training dataset too (probably COCO or VOC)?

Comment: yolo v3 uses a special multisize approach during training, they provide images is different input sizes, by resizing the convolutional layers. Did you try this?

Comment: Please, try to open my repo, and open pdf named comparison. [Here](https://github.com/kocica/training-dataset-generator/tree/master/results). Yes, during training the images are resized multiple times to different sizes. Yes i used initial dataset. What i dont understand is, why model trained on real dataset _can_ detect small size signs, while the model trained on generated dataset has problem with that. In every other way they have almost same results, just these small traffic signs cause problems. Even thought i tried to generate smaller signs. Like 10x10 pixels etc.

Comment: still cannot open the file on my mobile device. I'll try later on pc. Does your "trained on real images" network work on small signs of the artificial dataset? Maybe the augmentrd images just use unrealistic featues?

Comment: Yeah, it can detect them almost all of them with 100% confidence.

Comment: can you try to replace the stop signs from your real images by the artificial stop signs before training (same size). Should not be so much work, since you can just replace the ROI regions. Probably it just has to do with the better variance in the real images, but not sure... Maybe still some resizing stuff. Please mind, that in yolo v3 training, not only the images are resized during training, but the whole network architecture is resized, too (which is possible for a fully convolutional network). But since your training works for the real images, there seems to be a different problem.

Comment: @Micka -- Actually, what helped detecting small traffic signs was to change input size of neural network. I've been training and testing with input size 416x416, and after changing it to 832x832, detection increased a lot, and there was no need to retrain the network.