# Which is an advisable strategy for retraining YOLO Neural Network?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, yolo

I'm retraining YOLOv3 to detect Indian road signs and objects in video snippets and for training I have German road signs dataset and American road signs dataset. Since I have very less time to complete this project, it's hard for me to collect Indian road signs data for training and testing, I'm planning to use the data which I'm collecting majorly for testing and only a minor part of it for training (say 10% for training). Would this approach prove me effective to detect a few common traffic signs between those two datasets and Indian Roads or should I come up with an alternative strategy?

Also the size of the images in the German traffic signs dataset is around 32*32 and the input size of the network is 416*416. Would it be advisable to pad those images with zeros or should I resize them?

Comment: seems like you are using image classification dataset and try to use it for object detection. These are completely different tasks. However you can use the 32x32 sign images and warp the perspectively to a traffic scene to use them for a detection training

Comment: What do you mean by wrap them perspectively to a traffic scene?? Please elaborate!

Comment: with perspective tramsformations (image warping) you can place planar objects in a scene artificially scaled, rotated etc.. Have a look.at this link about how this can help you for object detection training: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791882/training-dataset-generator-in-opencv